# how to find direct link of PDF file called through XHR

Tags: pdf, xmlhttprequest

Is it possible to retrieve download link of PDF files on any of following links?

I captured send/request data between browser and WiFi adapter, but I couldn't find anything helpful from the logs.

```
http://ce-lib.iust.ac.ir/ViewFile.aspx?id=8355
http://ce-lib.iust.ac.ir/ViewFile.aspx?id=8117
http://ce-lib.iust.ac.ir/ViewFile.aspx?id=8030
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29556843/requesting-to-a-servlet-file-downloading-via-ajaxno-jquery-please

Comment: Thanks @RïshïKêshKümar for your reply. I found good info on the link, but still, it's not the answer to my question. I think the following script is handling the URLs, http://ce-lib.iust.ac.ir/js/l10n.js